# Find command: Exclude file pattern within specific folder

Tags: find

I would like the `find` command to exclude a certain file pattern within one folder, but not subfolders of that one folder.  For example, if I wanted to exclude `subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles*.tgz`, the following won't work because the asterisk matches consecutive characters including the folder name separator `/`:

```
find * -not -path 'subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles*.tgz'
```

The above excludes the following, which I don't want to exclude:

```
subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFilesAndMore/*.tgz
subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFilesAndMore/StillMore/*.tgz
```

I am using Gnu `find` version 4.9.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some `find` implementations support a `-regex` predicate which is the same as `-path` except that it uses regular expressions (though which variant varies with the implementation and options or other predicates) instead of shell glob patterns. Given that your `find` supports that non-standard BSD-style `-not` predicate, it's likely one of those.

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -regex '\./subdir1/subdir1\.1/UndesiredFiles[^/]*\.tgz'
```

Where we replace the `*` glob operator (same as regexp `.*`: 0 or more characters) with regexp `[^/*]` (0 or more characters other than `/`).

The regex is anchored by default, we don't need an explicit `^` or `$`.

As `.` is a regexp operator that matches any character, we need to escape it with `\.` (though `[.]` would also work) for it to match a literal `.` only (something very easy to overlook as `.`s are common in file names).

The `LC_ALL=C` is generally needed unless you can guarantee all the files and directories names are only made of valid characters in the user's locale (that also applies to your `-path` btw).

On BSDs, `-regex` takes standard basic regular expressions which can be changed to standard extended ones with the `-E` option (like for `grep` or `sed`). For GNU `find`, by default, that's regexps from an ancient version of emacs, but can be changed to various other flavours with [the `-regextype` predicate](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#index-_002dregextype). In any case, that particular regexp above will work with any variant.

---

With `find`s that don't support `-regex`, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! '(' -path './subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles*.tgz' \
  ! -path './subdir1/subdir1.1/*/*' ')'
```

That is filter out the `./subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles*.tgz` except those where what `*` has matched included at least one `/`.

Or you can have `perl` do the filtering:

```
find . -exec printf '%s\0' {} + |
  perl -l -0ne 'print unless m{^\Q./subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles\E[^/]*\.tgz\z}'
```

There we can use `\Q...\E` for what's inside to be considered as a fixed string, removing the need to escape any regexp operator. Here we do need to anchor the regex with `^` at the start and `\z` at the end (not `$` which in perl matches either at the end or before a newline at the end so would "wrongly" exclude a `$'UndesiredFiles.tgz\n'` file).

(replace `print` with `system "cmd", $_` to run a command with the path as argument).

With some (most) `find` implementations `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` can be replaced with `-print0`. Some `xargs` implementation support that output format with a `-0` or `-d '\0'` option:

```
find . -print0 |
  perl -0 -lne 'print unless m{^\Q./subdir1/subdir1\.1/UndesiredFiles\E[^/]*\.tgz\z}' |
  xargs -r0 cmd
```

`-l` option moved *after* `-0` so that the output record separator also be a NUL.

---

If using the `zsh` shell, you don't need `find`, you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/*~subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles[^/]#.tgz(ND)
```

Where `#` is the extendedglob equivalent of regex `*`, `~` is the *except* / *and-not* operator and `(ND)` is to apply `nullglob` (expand to nothing if there's no match) and `dotglob` (include hidden files) to that one glob expansion to match `find`'s behaviour. You can also add the `oN` qualifier to `N`ot `o`rder the list to even further match `find`'s behaviour.

`print -rC1 --` `print`s the list `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn, but you can of course use another command or loop over the list in a `for` loop.

`**/*` (match files with any name in any amount of subdirectories, short for `(*/)#*`) can be abbreviated to `**` if you set the `globstarshort` option.

---

In any case, note that while all of those exclude `./subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles-whatever.tgz`, they would *not* exclude a `./subdir1/subdir1.1/UndesiredFiles-whatever.tgz/other/file`. You'd need to adjust the patterns or make use of the `-prune` `find` predicate to also exclude them.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane!  Why I have not come across -regex, I cannot fathom.